# Java: Reflection against casting when you know superclass

Tags: java, reflection, downcast

I don't know exactly how to define my doubt so please be patient if the question has already been asked.

Let's say I have to dynamically instantiate an object. This object will surely be instance of a subclass of a known, immutable class A. I can dynamically obtain the specific implementation class.

Would it be better to use reflection exactly as if I didn't know anything about the target class, or would it be preferrable/possible to do something like:

```
A obj = (Class.forName("com.package.Sub-A")) new A();
```

where `Sub-A extends A` ? The purpose would be to avoid reflection overhead times...

Comment: This code doesn't compile. It doesn't even make sense. The result of `new A()` is an A, not the class of A, or the class of any of its subclasses. Please refine your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done via

```
Class.forName("com.package.Sub-A").getConstructor(param types).newInstance(param values)
```

And to avoid reflection overherad,  you just  cache constructor object.

Comment: Thank you, and what do you mean with "cache constructor object"?

Comment: getConstructor(...) delivers to you object of type (Surprise!!!!) java.lang.reflect.Constructor - and this object can be used to create multiple instaces of this class.